# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces 6.0.0'

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft.extensions.configuration

I'm trying to make the MSBuild plugin which will help to obfuscate the output file in seconds, I've run into a very weird error, which doesn't allows me to continue the development, the problem is some of the Nuget Packages asking me to use 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces 7.0.0' - Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 7.0.0, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.. Microsoft.Extensions.. 7.0.0, etc. I'm not able to downgrade these nuget packages because:

- I'm not able to work with IOptions properly.

Code that I'm using

```cs
public static ServiceCollection AddConfigurations(this ServiceCollection source)
{
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("protections.json", true, true)
        .Build();
    // Outputs '0' if this is a Microsoft.Extensions.. 6.0.0
    // With Microsoft.Extensions.. 7.0.0 everything is fine
    Console.WriteLine(configuration.GetSection("Protections").Get<List<ProtectionSetting>>().Count);
    source.AddOptions()
        .Configure<ProtectionSettings>(options => configuration.Bind(options));
    return source;
}
```

ProtectionSettings

```cs
public class ProtectionSettings
{
    public List<ProtectionSetting> Protections { get; set; }
}
```

ProtectionSetting

```cs
public class ProtectionSetting
{
    [JsonRequired] public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore] public bool Disabled => Enabled == false;
}
```

protections.json

```json
{
  "Protections": [
    {
      "Name": "NameHere",
      "Enabled": false
    },
    {
      "Name": "NameHere2",
      "Enabled": true
    }
  ]
}
```

### Workaround

Use 6.0.0 versions of Microsoft.Extensions, but I'm getting the problem with the configurations that they're all zero values and MSBuild asking me about `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces 6.0.0`, but this is not a solution, I'm still looking for a solution.. Also I've tried to use the Assmebly binding redirect, but this wont help me to solve the problem:

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces"
                                  publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51"
                                  culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What is the target framework for your project?

Comment: @GuruStron <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net462</TargetFrameworks>

Comment: Can you please post a full [mre]?

Comment: @GuruStron Yes, sure, now it should looks better